# If condition with "+" and "-" using awk

Tags: linux, awk, operators

I have a tab delimited text file like follows:

```
Entry1  2313   2421  +  schal_1
```

I wrote a awk command to test whether $4(column4) has "+" and if it is, then the $3(column3) value must be replaced with ($2+1) and if it is "-" then $2(column2) value must replaced with $3-1 but somehow, it didn’t gave neither any output nor any error. Here is my code

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} ; {if($4 == "+") {print $1,$2,$2+1,$4} else if($4=="-") {print $1,$3-1,$3,$4}}' file.txt
```

Dont know where is the mistake. Any guidance would highly appreciated.

Comment: What you describe is not possible given that script and that input file so try again to post a [mcve] and copy/paste the command line and the output when you execute `cat -v file.txt; awk '{print "<"$4">"}' file.txt; awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} ; {if($4 == "+") {print $1,$2,$2+1,$4} else if($4=="-") {print $1,$3-1,$3,$4}}' file.txt`. FWIW my money's on `Entry1` containing spaces and since you haven't set `FS="\t"` anywhere `$4` isn't where you think it is.

Comment: @EdMorton When I executed `cat -v fie.txt`, it gave me `` Entry1  2313  2421  +^M``
Later when I executed `awk '{print "<"$4">"}' file.txt`, then I got ``>+`` na finally when I tried run the awk command without OFS block, then ``awk '{if($4 == "+") {print $1,$2,$2+1,$4} else if($4=="-") {print $1,$3-1,$3,$4}}' ``still gives me no output. Kindly guide me. Is my if  condition is right?

Comment: Your file contains Carriage Returns (`^M`s) - execute `dos2unix` or similar (google it) on the file then try again. Your `if` condition could be improved on but it WILL do what you think it should given a valid input file.